# PHP - Match the 1st characters of a string with array value and return key

Tags: php, regex

I have a load of data

```
0134234XXX
0255234XXX
0843324XXX
080054XXXX
001342343XX
07800XXXXXX
003342343XX
```

and an array: (Key => Val)

```
[1] => [01]
[2] => [001]
[3] => [07]
[4] => [0845]
```

I am trying to write a function that will return the Key of the matching 1st characters
eg:

```
$keyNumber = findkey('001342343XX');

$keyNumber = 2
```

Comment: *I am trying..* then show what you have tried.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: I tried to write something, but... what is the expected result for `0255234XXX`? Is the input array `array('01', '001', '07', '0845')`?

Comment: Functionized as https://3v4l.org/XRUA0?

Comment: @chris85: That won't work if the array is `$values = ['01', '011', '0845', '001'];` and the string is `0110000`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The behavior for that scenario is unknown. The provided examples have no overlaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the OP wants an anonymous function, since it is likley to be reused on the array elements.

This is a slightly less efficient version of revo's method that will seek the longest match when a search array value also exists as the leading characters of another value.  ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dda401a0ceaaea9f79c702094f93a86274e26379))

```
$tin_foil_hat="on";  // <-- essential for this method ;)

function findkey($haystack,$needles){
    $match=0; // "No Match";
    foreach($needles as $k=>$v){
        if(strpos($haystack,$v)===0){
            $match=$k;  // overwrite any shorter previous matches
        }
    }
    return $match;
}

$haystacks=['0134234XXX','0255234XXX','0843324XXX','080054XXXX','001342343XX','07800XXXXXX','003342343XX'];
$haystacks[]='0110000XXX'; // for Wiktor
$needles=[1=>'01',2=>'001',3=>'07',4=>'0845'];
$needles[5]='011'; // for Wiktor
// This assumes shorter string contained in a larger string will be ordered first in $needles array.
// If no needles value is contained in another needles value, then revo's is the way to go (with early return).

foreach($haystacks as $haystack){
     echo $haystack,' => ',findkey($haystack,$needles),"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0134234XXX => 1
0255234XXX => 0
0843324XXX => 0
080054XXXX => 0
001342343XX => 2
07800XXXXXX => 3
003342343XX => 0
0110000XXX => 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Regular Expressions here:

```
$findKey = function($str) use ($values) {
    foreach ($values as $k => $v)
        if (strpos($str, $v) === 0) return $k;
    return false;
};
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/W7UMe)

Comment: It won't work if the array is `$values = ['01', '011', '0845', '001'];` and the string is `0110000`. Your code will say `0`, while it should be `1`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Why do you think it should be `1`?

Comment: @ChrisKerrison revo's method is the shortest, most efficient way to do this (though you may not want an anonymous function).  If, like Wiktor says, there is a chance of one value representing the start of another value, then just make sure that you order the longer values before the shorter ones in your needles array.